# How can I use javascript console to change the background color with #4286f4 or any other color picker number

Tags: javascript

This is a syntax issue, I believe:

I'm trying to add this to an input form in my personal website where if I enter the color picker's id number and click submit then the pages changes color.

But, I can't do it in javascript console:

```
    function onsubmitmusicform (input) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "'" + "#" + input + "'";
            return;
}
```

onsubmitmusicform("4286f4") returns undefined.

Comment: well you do not return anything so it is undefined.....

Comment: No need to add the `''` around...

Comment: You are setting the background color to `"'#4286f4'"`

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, it does return undefined, as you didn't give it anything to return. Its not changing the background however, because you're surrounding your element in quotes, for document.body.style.backgroundColor you just need to pass in

```
"#" + input
```

your final code will look like thus:

```
function onsubmitmusicform (input) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + input;
            return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding extra `'` on each side.

Your function should be like

```
function onsubmitmusicform (input) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + input;
            return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the single quotes. Do this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + input;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return false and drop the extra quotes. The return false will stop the submission

Like this:

```js
function onsubmitmusicform (input) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + input;
  return false; // kill the submit
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return onsubmitmusicform(this.color.value)">
  <input name="color" value="" />
</form>
```